# Setup UTF-8 in LEd

Tags: led-editor

How can I save my `tex` files in UTF-8 encoding with the LEd editor?

A friend of mine is trying to use my code, originally written in TeXstudio in Ubuntu, but is having encoding issues in LEd in Windows.

I did a quick inspection in LEd's interface, but an UTF-8 encoding option is nowhere to be found!

Comment: Use TeXstudio to convert the encoding. There is a button on the status bar below the editor.

Comment: I'm not sure that LEd supports UTF-8.

Comment: I'm almost sure it doesn't support UTF8, as it claims to be compatible with Windows 95 and 98.